# Google Plus sign in 'Choose an Account' dialog appears with No profile picture

Tags: android, android-studio

I integrated google plus sign in to android but when i clicked on 'Sign In' button the 'Choose an Account' dialog appears with No profile picture and all the other functionalitites are working fine.I am using below dependencies
         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
                'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
          [image] compile

```
 'package ctl.com.mythirdapp;
  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.ImageView;
       import android.widget.LinearLayout;
       import android.widget.TextView;

     import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
 import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
 import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
 import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
  import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
  import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
      import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
          import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
      import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
         import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

   public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
private ImageView imgProfilePic;
private TextView txtName, txtEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    // Customizing G+ button
    btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
}


private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}

private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        String email = acct.getEmail();

        Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

        txtName.setText(personName);
        txtEmail.setText(email);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfilePic);

        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn_sign_in:
            signIn();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_sign_out:
            signOut();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
            revokeAccess();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}

private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: could it be because you are using mobile data, and so the pictures takes longer to load?

Comment: No absolutely NOT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented it in my code, it working fine may be its help you. I used com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0.

```
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(Constants.GOOGLE_SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
            .requestServerAuthCode(Constants.GOOGLE_SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // [END configure_signin]

    // [START build_client]
    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

Comment: How to get GOOGLE_SERVER_CLIENT_ID?

Comment: by the Google developer console you get .json file, you can follow https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating