# Selecting account to use when clicking 'Integrate with Google' button

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

Our site is using the 'Integrate with Google' button to allow G Suite admins to install our web application without needing to go to the app marketplace (we're doing as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/button)). Unfortunately, if our user is signed into multiple Google accounts, the integrate button seems to just use whichever account they happened to sign into first, which might not be the right one. A workaround is to sign out of all accounts and back into the desired one, but we can't very well ask that of our users.

Is there some way to force the button to show an account selector? Or alternatively is there some way to provide a 'login hint' similar to [the one that the OAuth API takes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)?

Comment: You may refer with this link for the implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468010/google-plus-sign-in-choose-an-account-dialog-appears-with-no-profile-picture. However, this uses Google+ sign in.